# List view with multiple button in getview()

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

My app generating a list view(ie, list of audios) with 2 buttons and 3 text views in a row of a list.The two buttons made clickable by using adapter that implements base adapter.The one of the button is used for intent view and another to play the audio.When clicking the play button  i changed the background of button(play).But the problem is Multiple play buttons background was changed like in the positions 0,10,20,31,41... when i click 0 the row and also i wish to know how to change  background of selected list view to differentiate the playing audio from others...

pls..suggest me the solution for that.. thanks in advance
the following my adapter class

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_layout1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
            holder.Date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
            holder.Time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Time);
            holder.Duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Duration1);
            holder.view = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.View);
            holder.play = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Play);
            holder.r_layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r_layout);


            holder.Duration.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            holder.play.setBackgroundResource(0x7f020009);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View convertView) throws IllegalStateException 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //here is code for play/stop the audio
holder.play.setBackgroundResource(0x7f020009);





            }
        });
        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View convertView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("View","hai");
                Intent i=new Intent(context,audio_player.class);
                Bundle bd=new Bundle();

                String sel=itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getTitle();
                String dur=itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getDuration();


                bd.putString("audioID",sel);
                bd.putString("totalDuration",dur);

                i.putExtras(bd);

                System.out.println("After intent called");



                context.startActivity(i);
                ((Activity) context).finish();



            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView Title,Date,Time,Duration;
        ListView lv;
        Button view,play;
        RelativeLayout r_layout;
    }
}
```

Comment: first check clicking option is worked inside the `getView`?

Comment: Your problem solved or not??

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_layout1, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
        holder.Date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
        holder.Time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Time);
        holder.Duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Duration1);
        holder.view = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.View);
        holder.play = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Play);
        holder.r_layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r_layout);


        holder.Duration.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);




        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
 holder.play.setBackgroundResource(0x7f020009);
```

Comment: holder.play.setBackgroundResource(0x7f020009); i put this before retur convertView;But the new problem is when scroll down it again changed to the initial state while it is playing.I wish when it is playing the backgriund of the button will differentiated from others  even if sroll down .

Comment: I did as you said but multiple selection problem is solved.But i cannot change the button background of playing audio.By this code all buttons backgrounds are same when scrolling

Comment: yes i'm tried.but Still i didn't get a solution.The problem arrising when the scrolling the list view.It returns convertview!=null. i think thats why my code is not working

Comment: see when scrolling "convertview!=null" this is correct y because the unused row will be in convertview so when scrolling it will be !=null thats correct only..you have to concentrate on your logic how to do this..Can you post your onitemselectedlistener of listview??

Comment: Sorry i didn't used on itemClicklistner.What is the need of that? bcz i only want to the 2 buttons are clickable.that is i done in the getView() using holder(holderView).\

Comment: No ya..You want a particular position button's background to be changed in the listview..So only i suggested that..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I have facing same issue.I'm using button inside `getView`.`Button` click option not working.  instead of `Button` kindly use `textView`. And then write `OnClickListener()`

```
 holder.text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View convertView) {
   }
  };
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have had the same issue a while ago and here is the solution: 
First, put your code in the `BindView`part of the `customAdapter`, set and reset the background of every button because only setting without reset would apply the change of background to all the buttons in the list while scrolling, be careful with the context change. For example, to change text on a click, get the textview before the on click and not inside it. check the code bellow and comment for clarifications.
PS: don't copy/paste the code, it's not 100% correct because I used my full code and removed useless parts.

```
class ViewHolder {
TextView PhoneTV;
ImageButton player;

}
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    Log.i("myadapter", "bindView");
    if (view != null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.PhoneTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.one);
    holder.player = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        } 
                if(there is audio file){
        holder.player.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon);
            holder.player.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.player.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ImageButton playPause = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
                Log.i("click", "Clicked");
                    try{
                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                playPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon);
                            }
                        });

                        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                            Log.i("click", "Pausing");
                            mediaPlayer.pause();    
                            playPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon);
                            Toast.makeText(localContext, "Paused ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                        else{


                            new AsyncTask<MediaPlayer, String, String>(){

                                ProgressDialog pd;
                                AsyncTask at = this;

                                protected void onPreExecute() {
                                    // do pre execute stuff...
                                    super.onPreExecute();
                                    try{
                                        this.pd = new ProgressDialog(localContext);
                                        this.pd.setMessage("Please Wait..");
                                        this.pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                                        this.pd.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                at.cancel(true);
                                                playPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon);
                                                Toast.makeText(localContext, "canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }
                                        });
                                        this.pd.show();
                                    }catch(NullPointerException n){
                                        Log.i("play", "NPE pre");
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                protected String doInBackground(MediaPlayer... params) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                                        Log.i("click", "inside datasource and here it is: "+rec);
                                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(recording_file);

                                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } 
                                    Log.i("click", "Playing");

                                    return null;
                                }
                                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                                    // do post execute stuff...
                                    try{
                                        mediaPlayer.start();
                                        this.pd.dismiss();
                                    }catch(NullPointerException n){
                                        Log.i("play", "NPE post");
                                    }

                                }


                            }.execute(mediaPlayer);
                            try{
                                playPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_icon);
                                //Toast.makeText(localContext, "Playing..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }catch(NullPointerException n){
                                Log.i("play", "NPE out");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(IllegalStateException il){
                        Log.i("exception", "Player Illegal State Exception");
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```